# Addressing ECUs directly using ELM 327 dongle and ISO 9141

Tags: embedded, obd-ii, elm327

I have a VW Golf 4, which is quite old and talks KWP 2000 (ISO 9141) on its CAN bus. I use a dongle powered by ELM 327, connected to the OBD-2 port of the car.

I am trying to send messages individually to each ECU. I tried to change the header of the messages:
`AT SH 48 XX F1` (I hoped `XX` would be the ECU ID; `48` is the flag for "use physical addressing"). Any command I issue (e.g. tried `3E` for "tester present") returns `NO DATA` (I disabled automatic timeouts and set the timeout to maximum value).

Is there a way to send messages directly to the ECU? I am not interested in the set of data provided via OBD-2, neither do I want to re-flash the ECUs. At the moment I just try to find out which ECUs are available on the bus.

Thanks!

Comment: `3E` is not a valid UDS command, it is usually sent with a subfunction. What happens, if you try `3E 00`?

Answer (score 1):

VW works on Transport Protocol TP 2.0, hence you need to initialize with 0x200 header.

https://jazdw.net/tp20

See above link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If "ISO 9141" wasn't a typo, then what your car really uses is `KWP1281 over K-line`, not `KWP2000 over CAN`.

It is easy to test if you have VCDS, when you connect successfully to a module, you will see the protocol in the top-left corner, as follows:

- "KWP1281" = ISO9141 (K-line)
- "KWP2000" (or another number greater than 2000) = ISO14230 (K-line)
- "CAN" = KWP2000 (CAN-Bus)

If it does indeed use CAN, using an ELM327 is possible, as explained in the other answer containing TP2.0 info.

But if it uses the K-line (like I would expect an old Golf 4 to), unfortunately the ELM327 isn't up to the task, as VAG vehicles use a proprietary protocol. Your best bet is to use a microcontroller, like an Arduino, to emulate a tester.